# date format issue while generating excel from asp.net software

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have created a software in asp.net and for some reports i am generating excel file from gridview.
I already set server OS (windows server 2012 R2) date format to dd-mm-yyyy but still generated excel file is showing date format like mm-dd-yyyy till the date 12, from 13 it shows correct date format as i want like dd-mm-yyyy, please suggest

Comment: That is because you are exporting from a GridView. You lose the datatype in the process. Export from the source data instead.

Comment: Also, be aware that Excel date formatting affects **ONLY** how the date is displayed.  It has no affect on how an entered date is parsed.  That is controlled by the Windows Regional Settings.  So if there is a mis-match there, the dates will either be interpreted as text strings (eg: month > 12), or converted incorrectly.